# Error using gulp with bundle - HTML parsing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

So i got this very simple gulp task :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify({ entries: ['main.js'] })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify']);
```

Which is supposed to simply `browserify` my `main.js` to `bundle.js` and then store it in a `dist` folder. 
Problem is, it seems that gulp doesnt like it when parsing HTML because i got this error :

> events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^ Error: Parsing file C:\Dev\react_wkspc\main.js: Unexpected token (5:2)

my main.js is also very basic :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>First test of react!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('container');
);
```

and the error seems to come from this line `<h1>First test of react!</h1>,` which is, i believe, the proper way to uses React because it is the same script as [the official React doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html#using-react-from-npm)

i also tried with `babelify` and this script :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  browserify({
    entries: 'main.js',
    extensions: ['.js'],
    debug: true
  })
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify']);
```

and got the same error

> SyntaxError: C:/Dev/react_wkspc/main.js: Unexpected token (5:2)

Comment: You need Babel to use JSX with Browserify.

Comment: edited the post : not working with babel either

Comment: You need to setup babel with react preset.

Answer (score 0):

The missing steps from what I can read is

- add babelify
- make sure that you also have the proper babel presets installed such that your source can be parsed correctly.

Here is an example from a project of mine, with b being browserify

```
function bundleShare(b, output) {
  return b
    .transform(babelify.configure({
      presets: ["es2015", "react"]
    }))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(output))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/assets'));
}
```

In my package json I have the following dev dependencies

"

```
babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"babelify": "^7.2.0",
```

Comment: in my 2nd script i tired to use babelify with no success. I'm currently reading stuff about this and apparently i gotta to configure a .babelrc file. Any ideas where it could be though ?